# Why is the shtreimel worn balanced atop the head?

Tags: clothing, chasidut-hasidism, black-hats

It seems like many chasidim wear their shtreimel (and their weekday hats) balanced atop their heads, a size or so smaller than one might wear a hat in the secular world.

Is there an underlying reason for this, or is it just the style?  I have seen that the shtreimel is likened to a crown, which leads me to think there's more to it than liking the look.

Comment: It might be for comfort - they get quite hot, so wearing them higher they cover less of the head.

Comment: @Ariel, maybe, but then again, Minhag Avoseinu beYadeinu, right?

Comment: I wear a shtreimel that fits comfortably and won't fall off even under the most "extreme" circumstances...Dancing by a chasanah, dancing by simchas beis ha'sho'aveh, etc. They are generally custom made and fit the inside exactly to your head size and shape.

Comment: I thought the reason was to leave room for the tefillin shel rosh!

Comment: @DanF Cannot possibly be the reason as _shtreimlach_ are worn only on _Shabbos_ and _Yom Tov_ when the _tefillin_ are not worn.

Comment: @ezra I guess I don't know enough about minhag hashtreiml. I hang around Chaba"dniks like you :)

Comment: @DanF It's a shame Chabad doesn't wear a shtreimel. I think they're very cool. _Much_ cooler than black fedora.

Comment: @ezra They are cool. But I think the *knaitch* on the hat is also cool. Besides, be glad you only have to pay for a Borsalino instead of a shtreiml. In many cases, these guys are spending about 50% of their salary on it.

Comment: @DanF Yes, it's unfortunate there are no budget options for the shtreimel. (And I take back what I said about the Borsalino, they actually are very cool.)

Comment: @ezra See my comment / question below the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an element of style, but it is not exclusive to streimelach. Many chassidim wear hats that are "too small" too. Both are considered more modern, just as a high streimelach with "crown" (vertical fur tips), and many other clothing details.

There is are practical aspects too: The tails over the neck can get crushed against the stiff bekitche collar, and a more horizontal streimel reduces the risk of having it fly off during dancing.

However, the old custom is for the streimel to sit very low, even covering the ears. Today, the more extreme groups (e.g. like Neturei Karta) wear the streimel the lowest, almost touching the ears.

I wear hat size 59 and streimel size 58.

Comment: Hi Adam. I gather that Shtreimlach are very expensive. Some people I understand spend almot half their salary on a shtreiml. Isn't there something like a Shtreiml *Gemac"h*? If not, would you have any idea as to why no one has thought of that or a fund to help people buy one?