# Why do Hassidim wear hats that simulate what Non-Jewish czars and kings wore?

Tags: minhag, gentiles, chasidut-hasidism, hats

I heard from a few people that some of the hats that Hassidim wear such as shtreimelach and spodeks mimic the hat styles worn by previous kings and czars. Perhaps, I heard incorrectly, so feel free to provide correct info on where these styles came from.

If it is correct, I am curious as to why they allowed imitating these styles? Two reasons to this question: Isn't this a form of "chukot hagoyim"? Why would they want to mimic the dress style of kings, czars or other leaders that harmed Jews?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22306

Comment: I think Wikipedia gives a nice story of the [shtreimlach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtreimel), [spodeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spodik), and [kolpiks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolpik).