# What are the Names of the Hat types?

Tags: head-covering, hats

I don't know the names of the different hats worn by various Ashkenazic Jewish people. I know the term "Streimel", and I obviously know what that looks like, but I don't know what's the terms for:

-The flat top hat worn by Chassidish people (regular days)

-The bent hat worn by Lubavitcher Chassidim.

-The hat worn by contemporary Litvish people.

Comment: I don't think these hats have any special terms other than "derby", or as I've been hearing people call them lately - "black hat" or commonly "Borsallino" as that's the most common yeshivish / black hat brand being worn, today.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43303/5275

Comment: The hat worn by most chabad and litvish are the same just that chabad tends to keep the brim bent down and litvish tend to wear it both bent up and down.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Kagan and thanks for this first question. Not all questions are in scope for this site which is focused on Judaism (vs. Jews and their non-religious customs). Please don't be offended if this question gets closed. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 6):

> The flat top hat worn by Chassidish people (regular days)

This hat is called a "[samet](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%A1%D7%9E%D7%98)", and comes in "[flach](http://www.fersterhats.com/StaticFiles/galleries/29/2708201223453444.jpg)" (flat) or "[hoicher](http://www.fersterhats.com/StaticFiles/galleries/29/2908201220524308.jpg)" (higher) versions. There's also the [open-crown Homburg style hat](http://www.fersterhats.com/StaticFiles/temp/_Preview_240_1362111201618292211.jpg) that's common in Chassidish circles.

> The bent hat worn by Lubavitcher Chassidim

This is simply known as a fedora as in English or a "bent-down hat". The pinches in the crown are known as "knaitches" (pinches). They're usually manufactured by Borsalino, it's the [classic fedora](https://www.delmonicohatter.com/product/IT95.htm).

> The hat worn by contemporary Litvish people

This is the same hat that's worn by Lubavitch Chassidim, just it generally has a wider brim and a taller crown. I've usually just heard this called a fedora like in the above example or "the black hat".

Source: my own experience.

Comment: @Kagan You're welcome.

Comment: Re "contemporary Litvish people" - I noticed what might be a "retro" fashion trend occurring. From the 60's through roughly the 80's, Litvish wore fedoras but they weren't necessarily black. Esp. during the summer, many wore white or tan straw fedoras. Around the 90's through now, for some reason, felt black became the "only" fashion, and the brims got bigger. During the last about 5 years, I've noticed that the tan / white styles are coming back. Often in "frum fashion", dads become "nostalgic" and their sons imitate them and word / style spreads about.

Comment: @DanF I've noticed the same thing happening. Also in Lubavitch, more and more people are opting for short brims, some almost "stingy" even.