Chassidic Minhagim for different hats and bekitches
I am new to this forum and do not really know what help I can get but here is my question. I'm a Chabad chasid and this week including Shabbos I found myself in Kiryas Joel, and I saw many Satmar hasidim. What interested me was that some of them were wearing flat beaver hats, and some of them were wearing taller hats. Can anyone explain the difference in chassidic minhagim for wearing different hats, which are kept by Satmars?
I also saw a lot of people (what appeared as under bar mitzvah and unmarried) wearing bekitches, which I thought are only for married men. Can anyone explain the chassidic minhagim for wearing bekitches, which are kept by Satmars as well?

In Lubavitch, the chassidic levush is limited to married men, but most chassiduyos start from a younger age. This is due to anti-Semitic decrees in Tsarist Russia, forbidding Jewish dress. These decrees were less heavily enforced in Congress Poland and were non-existent in the Austro-Hungarian Empire, where Szatmar originated. This includes wearing a gartel, bekische, and/or rekel

yes i know this, but my question was why do they wear a bekitche on shabbos if theyre unmarried and why do they wear a platchiger biber hat and a hoiche hat?

but thank you for the information anyways

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95423/11486

Welcome to MiYodeya Ari and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

https://hasidicworld.wordpress.com/2020/06/26/15-types-of-hasidic-hats/


In regards to long coats such as rekels or bekishes in most communities the norm is to start wearing them from the age of bar mitzvah onwards. This is not universal as some will start wearing them even before. As far as I know the standard minhag in satmar is to start from bar mitzvah.

In regards to hats. There is the standard satmar hat which is flatter. Though you will see some variations. After the war certain chassidim groups such as satmar absorbed other chassidim. I think some of the variations are due to individual family customs.

In regards to chabad there was chabad levush in Russia and chabad levush as it developed in America. At one point there was no set levush for lubavitchers to wear and just what Jews in the area typically wore. This at times was more similar to what a lot of other chissidic groups today including streimels but not necessarily so. Today there is a distinct chabad levush which largely was created in the United States based on what the Rebbe wore and encouraged.


This is based on my own understanding as I don't know of a source or sefer to quote to you about the subject.

Hi thanks a lot for your input, so i know that satmar hasidim wear the rekel since bar mitzvah, and do they also wear the bekitche after bar mitzvah or bekitche is for after bar mitzvah only for those with rabbinical families?

@Ari if you feel your question was answered, please click a check mark or an up arrow. Thank you.
